# Find ancestors of given node in a n-ary tree c++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

Given a larg n-ary tree, I need to create a recursive function that prints all the ancestors of a leaf for example where the n-ary tree structure is given as

```
 typedef struct sNaryNode
 {
    int *data;
    int nchild;
    struct sNaryNode **child;
 } NaryNode;
```

Here is the function I used but that gives a wrong answer:

```
bool printAncestors(NaryNode *root, int *data) 
{ 
  int i=0;

   if (root == NULL) 
   return false; 

   if (root->data == data) 
   return true; 

   do
   {
      auto b=printAncestors(root->child[i], data);
      if(b)
      {   
          cout<<*root->data<<" ";
          return true;
      }
      else
          i++;
   }
   while(i<root->nchild);
}
```

Comment: You don't return anything if no child is found...

Comment: Offtopic: Why that many pointers? `int* data`: Do you reference some int e. g. in a totally different struct? If you just need the value, drop the pointer. `struct Node** children;`: Array of pointers??? Why wouldn't a normal array suffice already?

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to compare int pointers? E. g.: `int a = 7; Node root = { }; root.data = &a; int b = 7; printAncestors(&root, &b);` won't find the node even if `a` and `b` hold the same value...

Comment: @Aconcagua I used point to the node’ s data to implement the tree

Comment: Using pointers to data might or not be meaningful, that depends on the use case... Quite often, so, I see pointers being used when not appropriate, though (`struct Node** child` at least looks like one, without further information...). But by comparing the pointers themselves, you only can find a note if you use exactly that specific `int` the node points to. Are you sure this is what you want? Even *if* using pointers to data, wouldn't you rather want to find a node by value, i. e. `bool printAncestors(NaryNode* root, int data) { if(*root->data == data) }`?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a return value at the end, and you may enter the loop and access `root->child[i]` even if `root->nchild` is zero.
Both of those will cause undefined behaviour.

I would write this with a for-loop instead:

```
bool printAncestors(const NaryNode *root, const int *data) 
{ 
    if (root == nullptr) 
        return false; 

    if (root->data == data) 
        return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < root->nchild; i++)
    {
        if (printAncestors(root->child[i], data))
        {   
            cout << *root->data << " ";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact, I tried this function, but when I add a return value in the end it does not give values of ancestors so it does not enter the loop! I can't understand why

Comment: @WehbeD It might be that your value is not found due to pointer usage - see my latest comment to question...